# How to toggle view of divs based on multiple-choice select field

Tags: arrays, select, show-hide

A bit of a beginner question. I'm trying to apply a javascript for a Drupal content-posting page where, if a user selects X from a multiple-choice dropdown menu, then show divs 1,2 and 4. If they choose Y and Z, show those related fields.

I've already got a basic working script (even if a little ugly and beginer-ish), based off single choices. But I have a multiple-choice select dropdown.

I imagine it's done by putting selected choices in an array and checking against that. But this is a little beyond my skills, and I can't seem to find a good example for my scenario:

Heck, I can't even get past just showing an alert with the array of choices, let alone changing the code as I need. I see suggestions to use "$(this).val();" ... but I just get an error in console: "$ is not a function." I've tried jQuery syntax and javascript syntax, assuming I did it right. I'm pretty sure my Drupal module knows to accept jQuery, if that's the issue.

(as a side note, I'm sure there's a simpler/shorter way to toggle the divs using a class or custom attribute, too. But, with all the different IDs and scenarios, these methods didn't seem any shorter.)

As a novice in Javascript, I hope I've explained well. Here's the script I've made and want to change:

```
if(window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onload', whenLoaded);
} else {
    if(window.onload) {
        var curronload = window.onload;
        var newonload = function(evt) {
            curronload(evt);
            whenLoaded(evt);
        };
            window.onload = newonload;
    } else {
        window.onload = whenLoaded;
    }
}

function whenLoaded() {

  document.getElementById('edit-field-resource-type').addEventListener('change', function () {
  alert(this.value); // test to show worked.
       // alert($(this).val()); // tried for multiple choices - didn't work: 
       // "$ is not a function" .. I tried this way too: $(this).value;
       // var choices_array = [];

    var showWebinars = this.value == "taxonomy_term-14" ? 'block' : 'none';
    var showCaseStudies = this.value == "taxonomy_term-12" ? 'block' : 'none';
    var showWhitePapers = this.value == "taxonomy_term-11" ? 'block' : 'none';
    var showVideos = this.value == "taxonomy_term-13" ? 'block' : 'none';
    var showPodcasts = this.value == "taxonomy_term-62" ? 'block' : 'none';
    var showOther = this.value == "taxonomy_term-16" ? 'block' : 'none';
    var showInfographics = this.value == "taxonomy_term-10" ? 'block' : 'none';

document.getElementById('edit-post-webinar-copy-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;
document.getElementById('edit-field-event-duration-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;

document.getElementById('edit-field-infographic-file-wrapper').style.display = showInfographics;

document.getElementById('edit-field-video-embed-wrapper').style.display = showVideos;
document.getElementById('edit-field-video-third-party-wrapper').style.display = 

document.getElementById('edit-field-audio-file-wrapper').style.display = showPodcasts;
document.getElementById('edit-field-audio-file-link-wrapper').style.display = showPodcasts;

document.getElementById('edit-field-resource-file-wrapper').style.display = showWhitePapers;
document.getElementById('edit-field-resource-file-wrapper').style.display = showWhitePapers;

document.getElementById('edit-field-infographic-file-wrapper').style.display = showInfographics;


   });

}
```

Comment: If you want to use jQuery syntax, you'd need to require jQuery using something like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: yeah, I think there's an unrelated issue with Drupal not including that programatically. For now, I'm going to stick to javascript itself

Comment: I think I've made a little progress, with a nested function that loops through the select and adds results, if selected, into an array "selectedArray," using Javascript (not jQuery)... now, what I'm trying to determine is how to modify the ternaries below it, var x = this.value == term-in-array selectedArray ? 'block' : 'none' ... unless there's a better way to tackle this?

Comment: For DOM manipulation (which is what you're trying to do), I'd really recommend using jQuery because it's relatively lightweight and you'll avoid a lot of little bugs and issues with cross-browser compatibility...I have an idea and I'll post it shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, something similar to this should work for you (note that the `#` character will select elements by their `id` and the `.` character will select elements by their `class`.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#edit-field-resource-type').change(function(){
                var v = $(this).val();
                $('.all-options').hide(); //hide all the divs first, then only show the ones you want to show
                if(v==='something-1'){
                    $('.something-1').show();
                }
                else if(v==='something-2'){
                    $('.something-2').show();
                }
                // and so on...
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: if I'm understanding right, this is for a select with single choices? I need to account for multiple options in the select list. Maybe a jQuery version of looping through an array, like I posted in my ugly js solution? ... EDIT: oh wait.. I see the .val(); there. nevermind

Answer (score 0):

I will continue to explore the mentioned jQuery option, but need to investigate other issues with Drupal CMS, not allowing jQuery to work, even though it's added in the YML.

In the meantime, here's a modified script that worked for me. Ugly and long, but it worked. I welcome any feedback on how to streamline or better do this within my limitations

```
document.getElementById('edit-field-resource-type').addEventListener('change', function () {

         function loopSelected() {

             var selectedArray = new Array();

             var selObj = document.getElementById('edit-field-resource-type');
             var i;
             var count = 0;
             for (i=0; i<selObj.options.length; i++) {
               if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
                 selectedArray[count] = selObj.options[i].value;
                 count++;
               }
             }


             var showWebinars = selectedArray.includes("taxonomy_term-14") ? 'block' : 'none';
             var showCaseStudies = selectedArray.includes("taxonomy_term-12") ? 'block' : 'none';
             var showWhitePapers = selectedArray.includes("taxonomy_term-11") ? 'block' : 'none';
             var showVideos = selectedArray.includes("taxonomy_term-13") ? 'block' : 'none';
             var showPodcasts = selectedArray.includes("taxonomy_term-62") ? 'block' : 'none';
             var showOther = selectedArray.includes("taxonomy_term-16") ? 'block' : 'none';
             var showInfographics = selectedArray.includes("taxonomy_term-10") ? 'block' : 'none';

             alert(showWebinars);

             document.getElementById('edit-post-webinar-copy-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;
             document.getElementById('edit-field-event-duration-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;
             document.getElementById('edit-field-byline-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;

             document.getElementById('edit-post-webinar-copy-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;
             document.getElementById('edit-field-event-duration-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;
             document.getElementById('edit-field-byline-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;
             document.getElementById('edit-post-webinar-copy-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;
             document.getElementById('edit-field-event-date-range-wrapper').style.display = showWebinars;

             document.getElementById('edit-field-infographic-file-wrapper').style.display = showInfographics;

             document.getElementById('edit-field-video-embed-wrapper').style.display = showVideos;
             document.getElementById('edit-field-video-third-party-wrapper').style.display = showVideos;
             document.getElementById('edit-field-video-type-wrapper').style.display = showVideos;

             document.getElementById('edit-field-audio-file-wrapper').style.display = showPodcasts;
             document.getElementById('edit-field-audio-file-link-wrapper').style.display = showPodcasts;


           }

        loopSelected();

    });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the content type the normal way just use the "Conditional Fields" module.

You don't need to code this functionality.

Comment: Actually - that module is the reason I'm doing this. I tried Conditional Fields first. I ran into several issues, as it seems to not be fully baked and in Alpha (for D8) - or it is clashing with something in my Drupal install. Also, there's a security advisory warning on the Drupal org site, and this website is for a security company, so I couldn't take the risk